# Gradle how to setup project in child parent structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am very new to java. i want to setup Gradle project in such way so that all the project should refer to the internal folder for dependencies, and all project need to be in child-parent structure as below

```
root-folders
    -main-project(root-project gradle)
    -api(child-project)
    -ui(child-project)
    -cashflow(child-project)
    -views(all html/css/js files)
    -WEB-INF
        -lib(all jar files)
```

Everything is in Quarkus framework

Comment: You should use Gradle to manage the dependencies of the project, both libraries and sub projects. You should not need to have jar files inside the folders.

Comment: @aled i have some core business logic which i don't want to creates as subproject that way in want to keep the jar files in one place

Comment: Then create a separate project and install the artifact in a repository, local or remote.

Comment: You might want to learn about "multi-module" projects in Gradle (similar in Maven). Each module is like a separate project, producing an "artifact" such as a JAR file, but with coordinated builds of the sibling modules. One module is the parent, controlling the other modules’ build. Not to be confused with [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).

Answer (score 0):

In root dir you should have `settings.gradle` which describes the following:

```
rootProject.name = 'gradle-example'
```

to add child modules with names `foo` and `bar`:

```
include 'foo', 'bar'
```